# How to fade in a moving element at a particular location on the page?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a CSS animation that moves an element across the screen, and makes it fade in *at a particular point in space*. Due to usage of different easing functions, I can't tell at which point *in time* it would arrive there.

Here's an example that works in Chromium but not in Firefox:

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
}
@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0vmin;
    opacity: -3;
  }
  to {
    left: 90vmin;
    opacity: 6;
  }
}
.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;"></div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;"></div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;"></div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

In Chromium, the red blocks all fade in exactly above the blue block, thanks to the interpolation of `opacity` outside of its intended range of [0, 1]. It seems that Chromium interpolates the opacity first, and only then clamps it to the range [0, 1]. It's a dirty trick, but it sort of works.

It seems that Firefox does the opposite, however: it first clamps to [0, 1] before it applies the interpolation. The result is a smooth fade in from the far left to the far right of the track.

I can make it break in Chromium as well by animating `transform` instead of `left`, which by all logic shouldn't make a difference:

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
}
@keyframes mover {
  from {
    transform: translate(0vmin, 0);
    opacity: -3;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(90vmin, 0);
    opacity: 6;
  }
}
.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;"></div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;"></div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;"></div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

Which browser is correct here? And more importantly, **how can I achieve this effect without resorting to JavaScript?**

Exact browser versions:

- Chromium 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)
- Firefox 64.0 (64-bit)

Comment: I would say *you* are wrong doing so because you are using invalid values so each browser may handle this differently and try to show something despite the wrong values used

Comment: Nope, the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency) explicitly allows values outside this range and says they will be clamped. It just doesn't say _when_.

Comment: well, probably the word *invalid* is not appropriate but what I meant is that you are using *unwanted*/*unusual* values and since there is no defined algorithm of how they should be handled you are having different behavior ... It's not bad trying to understand why it's like that but IMHO we should avoid relying on *random* behavior. Anyway, Like you are asking, I am pretty sure we can achieve this differently.

Comment: So was I. Until I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that you want to slowly show the content, I would then use a different way to achieve a similar effect than opacity. I would consider an overlay above the element that I hide using another animation.

The idea here is to use an animation with the same metrics in order to have the synchronization with the mover animation and only show the element at the needed point of the space.

To do this I will consider a pseudo element that will have its width equal to the width of the path (`90vmin - 0vmin = 90vmin`) that will get animated in the opposite direction. this element will have a gradient coloration and this coloration will create the *magic*.

Here is the example:

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:#fff;
}
.mover:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  top:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  width:90vmin;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#fff 33%,transparent);
  animation: fader 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function:inherit;
}

.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}

@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0vmin;
  }
  to {
    left: 90vmin;
  }
}
@keyframes fader {
  to {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;">1</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;">2</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;">3</div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

To better understand what is happening let's change the coloration and remove the overlfow:

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  z-index:0;
  color:#fff;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
}
.mover:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  top:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  width:90vmin;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,green 33%,transparent);
  animation: fader 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function:inherit;
}

.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}

@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0vmin;
  }
  to {
    left: 90vmin;
  }
}
@keyframes fader {
  to {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;">1</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;">2</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;">3</div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

We can clearly see that the pseudo element is not moving because it's simply moving on the opposite direction as the main element and at the same speed. From our perspective it's fixed. Then we color the element until `33%` which is the `30vmin` thus our element will start showing at this moment.

By adding overflow and using the same color as the main background we create the fading illusion. Of course, if the main background isn't a solid color the trick will not work.

---

Another idea is to rely only on the background by adjusting and animating the `background-size`/`background-position` thus the pseudo element will simply have the same size as the main element:

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:#fff;
}
.mover:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  top:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#fff 33%,transparent);
  background-size:90vmin 100%;
  background-position:left;
  animation: fader 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function:inherit;
}

.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}

@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0vmin;
  }
  to {
    left: 90vmin;
  }
}
@keyframes fader {
  to {
    background-position:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;">1</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;">2</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;">3</div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

And to control the fading effect we increase the `background-size` by any multiplier of `90vmin`

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:#fff;
}
.mover:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  top:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#fff 33%,transparent);
  background-size:calc(var(--m,1)*90vmin) 100%;
  background-position:left;
  animation: fader 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function:inherit;
}

.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}

@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0vmin;
  }
  to {
    left: 90vmin;
  }
}
@keyframes fader {
  to {
    background-position:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;">1</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;--m:5">2</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;--m:20">3</div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

The bigger the size is the more we are close to an opacity effect.

**UPDATE**

Here is another idea where you can have transparency but no fading effect. The trick is to use a `clip-path` that we animate in order to show the element  at the needed position.

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  color:#fff;
}

.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite,
             fader 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}

@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0vmin;
  }
  to {
    left: 90vmin;
  }
}
@keyframes fader {
  from {
    clip-path:polygon(30vmin 0%,  100vmin 0%,
                                  100vmin 100%,
                      30vmin 100% );
  }
  to {
    clip-path:polygon(-60vmin 0%,  10vmin 0%,
                                   10vmin 100%,
                      -60vmin 100% );
  }
}

html {
  background:radial-gradient(pink,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;">1</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;">2</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;">3</div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

Here is an illustration to better understand what is happening:

[image]

The orange rectangle is the clipped area. It should start at the marker (`30vmin`) and end at the *end* considering the width of the element (`90vmin + 10vmin = 100vmin`). This means that initially we will not see the element.

That area should remain fixed to our perspective in order to be able to see the element only when it reach the marker thus we should move it in the oppsite direction and to do so we simply change the `clip-path`.

After animation is done we will have this:

[image]

The clipped area should end at the end of the element (`10vmin`) and it should keep the same dimension thus it need to start at (-60vmin).

---

We can now increase the `clip-path` area like we have done with `background-size` to control the *fading* effect and we can add an opacity animation and get closer to the initial requirement.

```css
.mover, .marker {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  color:#fff;
}

.mover {
  background: red;
  animation: mover 10s infinite,
             fader 10s infinite;
}
.marker {
  background: blue;
  left: 30vmin;
}

@keyframes mover {
  from {
    left: 0vmin;
  }
  to {
    left: 90vmin;
  }
}
@keyframes fader {
  from {
    clip-path:polygon(300vmin 0%,  1000vmin 0%, /* x10*/
                                  1000vmin 100%,
                      300vmin 100% );
    opacity:0;
  }
  to {
    clip-path:polygon(-600vmin 0%,  100vmin 0%,
                                   100vmin 100%,
                      -600vmin 100% );
    opacity:1;
  }
}

html {
  background:radial-gradient(pink,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: linear;">1</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-in;">2</div>
<div class="mover" style="animation-timing-function: ease-out;">3</div>
<div class="marker"></div>
```

<sup>Worth to note that clip-path is still not widely supported (https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) and you need to add the `-webkit-` prefix to cover the Safari browser.</sup>

Comment: Putting another element on top is a great idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my real situation because it has a complex background of layered gradients, instead of plain white...

Comment: @Thomas too bad ... any way you can share a real case with those backgrounds? probably I can find something else

Comment: I'd never heard of `clip-path` before, and I don't think I'll be able to use it. However, I think I can use a simpler idea: a wrapper element with `overflow: hidden`. Still wouldn't work in my actual situation (which has a more complex, circular motion that I used in this example), but I'll probably be redesigning that for other reasons anyway. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: @Thomas yes the wrapper solution will be good but I thought you will not be able to adjust the HTML and that the properties to define the point in the space need to belong to the animated element thus I didn't elaborate on this solution.